# What happened to Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Has there been some kind of forced update to Unity that I'm not aware of? Yesterday everything was working fine but today I'm unable to connect to services. Also my player settings look really weird:

[image]

That settings list is really long (probably over 500 settings) and I'm unable to find where to sign the application. It seems like there is settings for each individual platform even I've set my developing platform to Android. Also it seems like my in-app purchase plugin has disappeared `Assets/Plugins/UnityPurchasing/script/IAPDemo.cs(28,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IStoreController' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?`. Restarting Unity did not help.

Comment: Which Unity version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About your strange Inspector, I believe you are in `Debug` mode. To change it back to normal :

Click on the little menu icon at the top right of the inspector and click on "Normal"

[image: Debug mode]

For your other problems, try to :

1. Close Unity
2. Delete the Library (and Temp) folders
3. Open Unity and let it reimport all your assets

Comment: Actually I was not in Debug mode. I switched to Debug mode and back to Normal but it didn't work. Is it safe to remove the whole Library folder? And what do you mean by Temp folders?

Comment: If you close Unity, deleting the Library is safe (make a backup of your project if you don't want to take any risk). When Unity is open, you will have a folder named `Temp`. But sometimes, even if Unity is closed, this folder persists.

Comment: I have no idea what's actually stored in the library, but everything in it can be regenerated automatically (but takes time). It's safe to remove (or to not-transfer, eg. it doesn't need to be included in a Git repository).

Comment: Removing Library fixed all the problems. Now the inspector looks like it should. Services started to work so I was able to update my in-app purchase plugin to get rid of those nasty error messages. Thanks!